# Running xlwings on a server

Tags: python, server, xlwings

**Solved the problem by making sure that python27.dll and win32api into the PYTHON_WIN directory. The two files with an arrow were missing in the server folder (P:/)**

[image]

I am using udf module of xlwings and setting xlwings.bas configuration into a server. (I have my personal disk C:/ however other users need to run this macro and the file must be stored in P:/)

I have python, xlwings and other modules installed in P:/, but I get some strange error about importing os lib. Does any one have ever passed through this ?

Thanks in advance.

I got this from python:

"Python process exited before it was possible to create the interface object.
Command: P:\Python 27\python.exe -B -c ""import sys, os;sys.path.extend(os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'P:\Risco\Python Scripts')).split(';'));import xlwings.server; xlwings.server.serve('{2bb649ad-487e-48d5-ab31-24adaeefca59}')""
Working Dir: "

Xlwings.bas is set like this:

```
PYTHON_WIN = "P:\Python 27\python.exe"
PYTHON_MAC = ""
PYTHON_FROZEN = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\build\exe.win32-2.7"
PYTHONPATH = "P:\Risco\Python Scripts"
UDF_MODULES = "FetchPL"
UDF_DEBUG_SERVER = False
LOG_FILE = ""
SHOW_LOG = True
OPTIMIZED_CONNECTION = False
```

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer and accept it? This makes it easier to follow along.

Comment: Sure, Felix ! I am sorry about the delayed answer... vacation time. :)