# xlwings runpython EOL error

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

I have recently installed xlwings on my Mac and am currently trying to write a small programme to update some data(via requests). As a test, I tried to update the cryptocurrency prices via an API and write them into excel.
Without using runpython, the code works. However as soon as I run my VBA code,
I get this error:

```
 File "<string>", line 1

import sys, os;sys.path.extend(os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars('/Users/Dennis/Documents/crypto;

                                                                                                  ^

SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string liberal
```

I have searched numerous threads and forums, but can't seem to find an answer to my problem.
For a better understanding,

**my python code:**

```
import requests, json
from datetime import datetime
import xlwings as xw

def do():
   parameter = {'convert' : 'EUR'}

   #anfrage über API
   query_ticker = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker',   params = parameter)


   #anfragedaten in JSON-format
   data_ticker = query_ticker.json()


   wb = xw.Book.caller()
   ws0 = wb.sheets['holdings']

   for entry in data_ticker:

       # update eth price
       if entry['symbol'] == 'ETH':
        ws0.range('B14').value = float(entry['price_eur'])

       #update btc price
       if entry['symbol'] == 'BTC':
        ws0.range('B15').value = float(entry['price_eur'])

       if entry['symbol'] == 'NEO':
        ws0.range('B16').value = float(entry['price_eur'])

       if entry['symbol'] == 'XRP':
        ws0.range('B17').value = float(entry['price_eur'])

   now = datetime.now()
   write_date = '%s.%s.%s' %(now.day, now.month, now.year)
   write_time = '%s:%s:%s' %(now.hour, now.minute,now.second)

   ws0.range('B2').value = write_date
   ws0.range('B3').value = write_time

   wb.save('holdings.xlsm')
   #wb.close()
```

**this is my vba code:**

```
Sub update_holdings()
    RunPython ("import update_holdings; update_holdings.do()")
End Sub
```

Comment: from the looks of the error that you posted, you may be missing a single quote character from a string assignment

Comment: For me it seems more that there is something wrong with the way the file path is passed. I, however, do not have the slightest  clue what the 'import sys [..]' error refers to or what it tries to say to me? As you can see in my code, I did not work with the sys module.

Comment: edit: I have just downloaded the xlwings fibonacci example files and it throws the exact same error. Could be something with PYTHONPATH? Problem, I am not very experienced in this area..

Comment: maybe this ????   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353971/running-xlwings-on-a-server

Comment: try this in VBA code `RunPython ("import update_holdings")` .... see if it still throws the error

Comment: I bumped into a related issue where i saw EOL syntax error after i set PYTHONPATH with a windows path that contains space. Remove the space from folder path may help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. I just wanted to post the solution for anyone who might be confronted with the same issue.

I went to check my xlwings.conf file, in order to see the setup for "INTERPRETER" and "PYTHONPATH". I never did editing on this, however, it was formatted incorrectly.

The **correct** format is:

```
"INTERPRETER","pythonw"
"PYTHONPATH",""
```

My config file was setup this way:

```
"PYTHONPATH","
"
"INTERPRETER","Python"
```

Also, the path to my python was set incorrectly by default. Even though my command line works with Anaconda python 3.6, "pythonw" used the interpreter set in .bash_profile referenced to python 2.7 which came pre-installed with macOS.
Editing the config file "INTERPRETER" solved this issue.

Thanks everyone.